# Diferença entre relato e relatório?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática

Alguém poderia me ajudar qual é diferença entre **relato** e **relatório**?

> Exemplos:

> Como elaborar um excelente relatório sobre o status do projeto?

> Ele ouvia, com lágrimas, o relato do acidente.

Pelo os exemplos e procurando no internet me pareceu que o relato é mais informal e o relatório mais formal, ou seja, o relatório deve ser usado para situações acadêmicas, etc..

Alguém poderia esclarecer mais para mim, por favor.

Agradeço em adiante!

Comment: Relato = Um resumo ou a história do que aconteceu; Relatório = Um documento sobre com detalhes sobre algo (projeto, por exemplo).

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, «Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.» ; )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um relato é uma narrativa em que alguém *relata* o que aconteceu ou está acontecendo. Pode ser feito por escrito, mas também pode ser um relato oral. Pode ser mais ou menos direto ou objetivo, fiel aos fatos ou vago, claro ou confuso.

Um relatório, por outro lado, é sempre um documento. Trata-se de um "relato oficial", um texto que em geral é assinado e fica registrado, uma peça que alguém escreve para relatar objetivamente os resultados (provisórios ou definitivos) de uma pesquisa, os detalhes essenciais de um incidente, os dados envolvidos num processo. Pode ser o relatório de uma pesquisa acadêmica, de uma ocorrência policial, da contabilidade semestral de uma empresa etc.